# SQL Server - minimum value on row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a single row and two columns. Can I obtain the minimum value from the row using an SQL query?

```
    value1 value2
1     43     39
```

The query should return the value 39.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest method is probably `apply`:

```
select t.*, v.min_val
from t cross apply
     (select min(val) as min_val
      from (values (value1), (value2)) v(val)
     ) v;
```

For just two values that are not-null, you a `case` expression is also simple:

```
select t.*,
       (case when value1 < value2 then value1 else value2 end) as min_val
from t;
```

However, this does not ignore `null` values.  And it does not generalize quite as easily as one would like.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly **Gordon's** answer (+1) is more performant and would be my first choice, but if by chance you are looking for a more "generalized" version, here is a simplified JSON approach.

This may be helpful if you have numerous or variable columns.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,value1 int,value2 int)
Insert into @YourTable values
(1,43,39)

Select A.*      
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
              Select RowMin = min(Value)
               From  ( Select Value=try_convert(int,Value)   -- << Set desired Datatype
                        From  OpenJson( (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper ) ) 
                        Where [Key] not in ('ID')
                     ) J
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  value1  value2  RowMin
1   43      39      39
```